# What is the name of this moth and why does it have an extra wing?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

[image: Top View of the moth of length 15mm. Seen in Kerala, India on March 2019][image: Back view of the moth][image: Front view of the moth]
Moth of length 15mm. Seen in Kerala, India on March 2019. Third Unusual wing part visible. Without mobile flash the colour of moth visible is completely black.

Comment: This isn't a moth, it's a planthopper (Order Hemiptera, suborder Auchenorrhyncha, infraorder Fulgoromorpha, Superfamily Fulgoroidea [in which there are over twenty families worldwide; which is represented here I cannot guess]).  The "extra wing" is the right hind wing displaced (more than likely due to injury).

Comment: @ArthurJFrost Can you please make this comment into a full answer? Then you can get the credit for it. Additionally, answering in the comments in not liked here.